# Apache Hive fails to initialize on Windows 10 and Cygwin

Tags: windows, hadoop, hive

I have Hadoop/HBase/Pig all running successfully under windows 10. But when I go to install Hive 3.1.2 using [this guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-apache-hive-3-1-2-on-windows-10-70669ce79c79) I get an error initializing Hive under Cygwin:

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Hadoop/Hive/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1357)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1338)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJar(JobConf.java:536)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJarByClass(JobConf.java:554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.<init>(JobConf.java:448)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.initialize(HiveConf.java:5141)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.<init>(HiveConf.java:5104)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.<init>(HiveSchemaTool.java:96)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:1473)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

I've found this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719538/failed-to-initialize-schema-for-hiveserver2-in-apache-hive-3-0-0-on-cygwin-wind) about this problem, however the solution was create a symlink to the appropriate path for cygwin under a windows admin command prompt, and I have already done that with this command:

```
mklink /J  D:\cygdrive\d\ D:\
```

How can I get around this problem under windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the first error I'd found (and posted about in the OP), I had to go to the `$HIVE_HOME/lib` directory and remove this old guava library file: `guava-19.0.jar`

I had to make sure that the guava library I'd copied from the Hadoop library was there: `guava-27.0-jre.jar`

On the next attempt I got a different error:

```
schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
Error: FUNCTION 'NUCLEUS_ASCII' already exists. (state=X0Y68,code=30000)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!
Underlying cause: java.io.IOException : Schema script failed, errorcode 2
Use --verbose for detailed stacktrace.
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

I've found the solution to that problem [here](https://medium.com/@chanakyahosamani/finally-found-a-solution-to-overcome-the-below-2-errors-61516ba7efa2).

What I've had to do there was to go to the `$HIVE_HOME/scripts/metastore/upgrade/derby/` directory to locate the `hive-schema-3.1.0.derby.sql` file, then edit and find and comment out these lines:

```
--CREATE FUNCTION "APP"."NUCLEUS_ASCII" (C CHAR(1)) RETURNS INTEGER LANGUAGE JAVA PARAMETER STYLE JAVA READS SQL DATA CALLED ON NULL INPUT EXTERNAL NAME 'org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.adapter.DerbySQLFunction.ascii';

--CREATE FUNCTION "APP"."NUCLEUS_MATCHES" (TEXT VARCHAR(8000),PATTERN VARCHAR(8000)) RETURNS INTEGER LANGUAGE JAVA PARAMETER STYLE JAVA READS SQL DATA CALLED ON NULL INPUT EXTERNAL NAME 'org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.adapter.DerbySQLFunction.matches' ;
```

Once those 2 lines were commented out, I changed to the `$HIVE_HOME/bin/` directory and re-ran the `schematool -dbType derby -initSchema` command and this time it was a success!

```
Initialization script completed
schemaTool completed
```

I hope someone else may find this answer useful.